# Can Karate-Gatling scripts be used to have distributed testing/clustering for performance testing

Tags: karate

We are currently using `Jmeter` for API performance testing in distributed mode (1 master + 3 slaves) as need to generate 10k requests.

Now using `Karate` for API functional testing and could integrate with `Gatling` using `Maven` dependencies successfully. As documentation says I could inject users and duration in these scripts and run>generate report (tested for 10 users).

Kindly guide, having below queries:

1. Is it possible to make these Karate-Gatling scripts to run as we do in Jmeter distributed mode.
2. How many users can be injected using Karate-Gatling scripts in a single machine (AWS/GCP mini instance/VM). 
   I guess this might vary how fast the application responds/volume.

I have gone through Jmeter Vs Gatling and looks like Clustering/distributed mode is supported only in Gatling paid version.

Comment: the answer is here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing#gatling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Gatling Performance Testing Pros and Cons](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-performance-testing-pros-and-cons/) article:

> If you don’t want to pay for [Gatling FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/), but you need to take your load test a little bit further, it may not be so easy to distribute the load as it is with JMeter. Despite that, not all is lost, as Gatling actually provides a way to distribute the load with the free version of the tool.
>
> The way of distributing load in Gatling can be found [here](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/cookbook/scaling_out/#scaling-out-with-gatling-open-source), but the main idea of Gatling’s distribution is based on a bash script that takes care of executing the Gatling scripts located in the slaves machines, which then sends the logs generated by the simulation to the master machine, where the consolidated report will be built.

So you can kick off several Gatling instances on several hosts and use the Bash script provided in order to run your test simultaneously on different machines. You might also want to use [`ssh-copy-id` command](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) to avoid entering the password for each machine